# How to get concerned specific unspent(coin selection algorithm) from list of unspents in a wallet to calculate transaction size

Tags: bitcoin-core, transaction-fees, listunspent

I have a problem to calculate dynamic transaction fees. The problem which i am facing is to calculate the transaction size.
When i have one unspent in my wallet it is too easy to calculate transaction size. but when there are multiple unspents in wallet i think then there is some coin selection algorithm to calculate the best unspent or combination of unspents.
I have compiled document 
 [document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XvmkeZnFgjC0vLQlPtCk2IInaolAmPUj16S2gl_eS2Q/edit)  that explains this problem completely.

I need opinion in which way i wanna move? whether to develop own coin selection algorithm or there are some other options exist?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to calculate the size for? To calculate the transaction fee before coin selection? During selection? Or after?

Comment: In a simple words i just want to get the size of transaction which i am going to broadcast. When i got the size then i will calculate transaction fees.

Comment: If you just want to see the transaction fee before it is broadcast, use the raw transaction api (`createrawtranscation`,`fundrawtransaction`, etc.) or the psbt api (`walletcreatefundedpsbt`,`walletprocesspsbt`,etc.) and make the transaction. Then inspect it before you broadcast it.

Comment: I have done by using https://github.com/bitcoinjs/coinselect